# SectionList Scroll to specific section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to scroll a sectionList to a specific section when a button is tapped.
I get this error every time:

> Uncaught TypeError: scrollRef.scrollToLocation is not a function.

What I'm I missing?

```
var scrollRef = useRef()


const onScroll = () => {            
        scrollRef.current.scrollToLocation({
            sectionIndex: 1,
            viewPosition: 0,
            itemIndex: 1,
        })
    }

     <SectionList
                style={styles.sectionList}
                ListHeaderComponent={<ChefHighlight chef={props.chef}/>}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                sections={ data }
                renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.headerView}>
                            <Text style={[globalStyle.textPrimary, styles.sectionTitle]}>{section.title}</Text>
                            <View style={{paddingLeft: 20, alignItems:'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <MaterialIcons name="date-range" size={18} color={colors.textTertiary} />
                                <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 6, marginLeft: 8, color: colors.textTertiary, fontSize: 14, marginTop: 8, }}>Delivers on {section.title}'s</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    );
                }}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return <ComboCell item={item} onOpen={onOpen}/>
                }}

                onScroll={Animated.event(
                    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset:  { y: scrollY }}}],
                    // { useNativeDriver: true }
                  )}
                
                
                ref={scrollRef}
                ListFooterComponent={<View style={{width: '100%', height: 100}}/>}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `getItemLayout` if you use `scrollToLocation`